# Create table with Distinct Account Number, first Date in R

Tags: r

I have data as below:

```
MTH_KEY     ACCOUNT_NUMBER      NPL_DATE     OUSTANDING_BALNCE
201405          1234            05-05-14        $40.5
201405          1234            20-04-14        $65.5
201405          1234            20-04-14        $65.5
201405          1234            16-04-14        $70.5   
201406          1234            01-04-14        $80.5
201406          4321            15-06-14        $40.5
201406          4321            15-05-14        $50.5
201407          4321            01-04-14        $60.5
201407          5678            04-06-14        $48.5
201407          5678            05-07-14        $45.5
201407          5678            05-08-14        $35.5
```

I want to filter data with unique Account_number, first "NPL_DATE" and its "OUSTANDING_BALANCE"  to have the expected result as below:

```
MTH_KEY     ACCOUNT_NUMBER      NPL_DATE       OUSTAN_BALANCE       
201406          1234            01-04-14        $80.5   
201407          4321            01-04-14        $60.5
201407          5678            04-06-14        $48.5
```

Thank you for your help!!
[Please Check sample Picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6QHp.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little heads up here, I will try to address this question by using the package `data.table`. I will also assume the data is in a `data.table` called `LGD_data_update`, as pointed out in your comment.

So, you will need this.

```
 library(data.table)
 LGD_data_update <- data.table( LGD_data_update)
```

In this case, you first need to sort the rows by date. However, the dates are not formatted to include the complete information of years.

You can do that by

```
 LGD_data_update[, NPL_DATE := paste0(substr(NPL_DATE, 1, 6), "20" ,substr(NPL_DATE, 7, 8))]
 LGD_data_update[, NPL_DATE := as.POSIXct(NPL_DATE, format = "%d-%m-%Y")]
```

Then, you can sort by the dates

```
 LGD_data_update <-  LGD_data_update[sort(NPL_DATE), ]
```

From here, I would create a placeholder to give a cumulative sum based on the records, by each account number, so that only the first record will be 1.

```
LGD_data_update[, Foo := 1]
LGD_data_update[, Foo := cumsum(Foo), by = "ACCOUNT_NUMBER"]
```

Then, we will only select the columns where the placeholder (Foo) has a value of 1, as those will be the earliest NPL Dates.

```
 LGD_data_update <-  LGD_data_update[Foo == 1, ]
```

If necessary, remove the placeholder

```
 LGD_data_update[, Foo := NULL]
```

Comment: @Sophanna, would you mind letting me know what error(s) are returned, if any?

Comment: How to create DATA you have mentioned?

Comment: It is stated in my answer that DATA is assumed to be the name of the table that you have, since I do not know how you name your table in R.

Comment: @Sophanna Alright, I have updated the answer. Can you try it again and see if it works?

Comment: @Sophanna, it changes the class of the table, which allows some operations to be done in simpler syntax which I have used.

This is for your reference.
https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.datacamp.com/img/blog/data+table+cheat+sheet.pdf

Comment: LGD_data_update[, NPL_DATE := as.POSIXct(NPL_DATE, format = "%d-%m-%Y")]    Turn my NPL_DATE to NA value

Comment: > LGD_data_update <-  LGD_data_update[sort(NPL_DATE), ] become
Error in `[.data.table`(LGD_data_update, sort(NPL_DATE), ) : 
  i has not evaluated to logical, integer or double

Comment: @Sophanna Does this line

`LGD_data_update[, NPL_DATE := paste0(substr(NPL_DATE, 1, 6), "20" ,substr(NPL_DATE, 7, 8))]`

work as expected?

Comment: This work as expected and my NPL_DATE become YEAR-MON-02020

Comment: @Sophanna I would expect it to be "05-05-2014", "20-04-2014" and so on and so forth though.

Comment: In fact your code work well: LGD_data_update <- data.table(LGD_data_update)
LGD_data_update[, Define_count := 1]
LGD_data_update[, Define_count :=  cumsum(Define_count), by = "ACCOUNT_NUMBER"]
LGD_data_update <-  LGD_data_update[Define_count == 1, ]

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way using `dplyr` -

```
LGD_data_update %>%
  arrange(ACCOUNT_NUMBER, NPL_DATE) %>%
  distinct(ACCOUNT_NUMBER, .keep_all = T)
```

Comment: What does df refer to?

Comment: you can replace it with your actual dataframe name. I just edited it based on your comment on another answer.